# Pass values from PHP to HTML without Session and cookies

Tags: php, post

I am using PHP 5.3 without frameworks.

How can I pass values from a PHP file to another PHP or HTML or Javascript File?

Using `$_POST` I can do it but how to pass values without Form?

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve here?  A good answer depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: am new to php and trying to explore it.. I fetched values from MYSQL and that has to be sent to HTML without $_SESSION and $_COOKIES.

Comment: You should post your code.  That way we can see what you're trying to do and help more accurately within that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **PHP to PHP**

  With cURL

  ```
          $url = 'http://domain.com/get-post.php';
      $fields = array(
                  'lname'=>urlencode($last_name),
                  'fname'=>urlencode($first_name),
                  'title'=>urlencode($title),
                  'company'=>urlencode($institution),
                  'age'=>urlencode($age),
                  'email'=>urlencode($email),
                  'phone'=>urlencode($phone)
              );

      //url-ify the data for the POST
      foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
      rtrim($fields_string,'&');

      //open connection
      $ch = curl_init();

      //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

      //execute post
      $result = curl_exec($ch);

      //close connection
      curl_close($ch);
  ```
- **PHP to HTML**

  `echo` (since html is client-side, assuming it's your html and you're not scraping or injecting)
- **PHP to JS**

  Same as PHP to HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can just append them to a query string, without using a form.

`example.com/page.html?var1=data&var2=data`

As far as not using a form, sessions or cookies go, I think you're running out of options.

Passing around hidden inputs is an acceptable way to do it, but it requires forms.

Is there any reason why you can't (don't want to?) use sessions, cookies or forms?

Comment: Thank you :-) but what will be in case of array variable??

Comment: And using GET will display it with url na?? Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: GET does show in the URL.  If you want to do an array, use it like so: `var[1]=data&var[2]=data`

Comment: Can you show what you have written so far?  I might have misunderstood what your original goal was... You might just need echo statements.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want send value from Client end (HTML).

Don't know why you don't want use session!

But there is way I can suggest is to use Database, Save value into Database using jQuery Ajax, and using jQuery Ajax you can send data to PHP end with using "form" also.

After saving into DB you can query it back to any Page.

Hope this will help you !

Reference :
[jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Thanks

Comment: Not from client to server.. This is from server to client.. Result set of select statement (written in .php file) to be sent to .html file. $arrVariable = resultset of select * from tablename. This $arrVariable should be passed to HTML for display in browser. Am new and have to learn AJAX

Comment: Still I am feeling that you can post data using AJAX without using form, Go learn jQuery AJAX first, It might solve your problem